# Has anyone gotten Push Notifications to work successfully with React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Just a general question, I want to build an iPhone using React Native, but I need push notifications (and websockets), and I just want to check if anyone has been able to get them to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We have Push Notification via Parse in production and use them heavily in our chat client.

Comment: thanks - do you have to use Parse to send push notifications? can you use own server?

Comment: The react-native part is completely unaware of any backend. It just gives you the device identifier and handles incoming notifications. You can use what ever backend you like.